# Error ORA-12154 in Oracle Data Integrator

Tags: oracle

I get the error when I run a mapping.

I've created a "New Data Server"

[image]

I can successfully test the connection by clicking on "Test Connection" button.

But the mapping cannot be run successfully. The full error message is below:

```
ODI-1228: Task Merge rows-IKM Oracle Merge-Load USERS fails on the target connection DB-TARGET.
Caused By: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-12154: TNS:невозможно разрешить заданный идентификатор соединения

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:495)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:447)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1055)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:624)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:253)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:613)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:214)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:38)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:891)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1194)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeInternal(OracleStatement.java:1835)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute(OracleStatement.java:1790)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.execute(OracleStatementWrapper.java:301)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.execution.sql.SQLCommand.execute(SQLCommand.java:205)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.execution.sql.SQLExecutor.execute(SQLExecutor.java:142)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.execution.sql.SQLExecutor.execute(SQLExecutor.java:28)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.execution.TaskExecutionHandler.handleTask(TaskExecutionHandler.java:52)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.execution.SessionTask.processTask(SessionTask.java:206)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.execution.SessionTask.doExecuteTask(SessionTask.java:117)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.execution.AbstractSessionTask.execute(AbstractSessionTask.java:886)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.execution.SessionExecutor$SerialTrain.runTasks(SessionExecutor.java:2225)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.execution.SessionExecutor.executeSession(SessionExecutor.java:610)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.processor.TaskExecutorAgentRequestProcessor$1.doAction(TaskExecutorAgentRequestProcessor.java:718)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.processor.TaskExecutorAgentRequestProcessor$1.doAction(TaskExecutorAgentRequestProcessor.java:611)
    at oracle.odi.core.persistence.dwgobject.DwgObjectTemplate.execute(DwgObjectTemplate.java:203)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.processor.TaskExecutorAgentRequestProcessor.doProcessStartAgentTask(TaskExecutorAgentRequestProcessor.java:800)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.processor.impl.StartSessRequestProcessor.access$1400(StartSessRequestProcessor.java:74)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.processor.impl.StartSessRequestProcessor$StartSessTask.doExecute(StartSessRequestProcessor.java:702)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.processor.task.AgentTask.execute(AgentTask.java:180)
    at oracle.odi.runtime.agent.support.DefaultAgentTaskExecutor$2.run(DefaultAgentTaskExecutor.java:108)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: Error : 12154, Position : 154, Sql = 
    MERGE 
  INTO TARGET.USERS USERS
  USING
  (
SELECT 
  USE.NAME AS NAME ,
  USE.PASSWD AS PASSWD ,
  USE.USER_ROLE AS USER_ROLE   
FROM 
  **SOURCE.USERS@"MySource" USE**  
  ) MERGE_SUBQUERY
  ON
  (
    USERS.NAME = MERGE_SUBQUERY.NAME 
   )
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT
    (
      NAME ,
      PASSWD ,
      USER_ROLE 
    )
    VALUES
    (
      MERGE_SUBQUERY.NAME ,
      MERGE_SUBQUERY.PASSWD ,
      MERGE_SUBQUERY.USER_ROLE 
    )
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET
      PASSWD = MERGE_SUBQUERY.PASSWD ,
      USER_ROLE = MERGE_SUBQUERY.USER_ROLE    , OriginalSql = 
    MERGE 
  INTO TARGET.USERS USERS
  USING
  (
SELECT 
  USE.NAME AS NAME ,
  USE.PASSWD AS PASSWD ,
  USE.USER_ROLE AS USER_ROLE   
FROM 
  SOURCE.USERS@"MySource" USE  
  ) MERGE_SUBQUERY
  ON
  (
    USERS.NAME = MERGE_SUBQUERY.NAME 
   )
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT
    (
      NAME ,
      PASSWD ,
      USER_ROLE 
    )
    VALUES
    (
      MERGE_SUBQUERY.NAME ,
      MERGE_SUBQUERY.PASSWD ,
      MERGE_SUBQUERY.USER_ROLE 
    )
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET
      PASSWD = MERGE_SUBQUERY.PASSWD ,
      USER_ROLE = MERGE_SUBQUERY.USER_ROLE    , Error Msg = ORA-12154: TNS:невозможно разрешить заданный идентификатор соединения

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:499)
    ... 30 more
```

Don't be confused with russian description of the error ORA-12154.
It means TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified.

tnsnames.ora file exists. I can also connect using SQL Developer

After some investigation it seems to me that the line

```
SOURCE.USERS@"MySource" USE
```

is the culprit

But before this script was executed ODI executed another script and executed it successfully. Below are its contents:

```
create database link "MySource" connect to SOURCE identified by <@=odiRef.getInfo("SRC_PASS") @> using '***'
```

Comment: Is there only one TNSNAMES.ORA file there? If there are several files (as every Oracle product contains its own copy), maybe you aren't using the correct file ... If that's the case, consider creating TNSADMIN environment variable which points to a directory that contains TNSNAMES.ORA file you'd keep up-to-date, so that every Oracle software product uses the same data.

Answer (score 0):

I ran both queries in SQL Developer and replaced `<@=odiRef.getInfo("SRC_PASS") @>` with the real value.

I could reproduce the error.

I ran the query below to be sure that the dblink had been created:

```
select * from all_db_links;
```

Then I ran against a discussion where someone suggested to create dblinks in this way:

```
create database link "MySource" connect to SOURCE identified by *** using 
'(DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = oracle.****.***.**)
    )
)';
```

It worked. I could use this link in the subsequent queries. But I noticed that a shorter way was to create a dblink by using SID only:

```
create database link "MySource" connect to SOURCE identified by *** using oracle;
```

So I switched to ODI and changed the connection strings used in all the data servers from `jdbc:oracle:thin:@<host>:<port>/<service name>` to the format `jdbc:oracle:thin:@<host>:<port>:<sid>`

This resolved the isssue. I could run the mapping successfully.

Not sure why a dblink that is created based on service name cannot be used.

Oracle doesn't forbid it according to the docu

**CREATE DATABASE LINK:**

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5005.htm